# How to set next null value with first value using select or view function in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select

Please help me how to solve this...I'm newbie for this...

```
SELECT idt, date_played, date_end, duration FROM `v_currentshow`
```

where date_played, date_end, and duration fields are DATETIME

```
idt    date_played          date_end               duration
1      2013-03-13 22:33:48  2013-03-13 21:58:20    00:35:28
2      NULL                 NULL                   00:02:11
3      NULL                 NULL                   00:00:32
4      NULL                 NULL                   00:36:42
5      NULL                 NULL                   00:01:30
6      NULL                 NULL                   00:25:12
7      NULL                 NULL                   00:01:37
.
.
.
n      NULL                 NULL                   00:02:32
```

The questions are..

1. How can we set the next date_played null value like in idt=2 and another idt, start with date_end value in idt=1 and counting so on through entire table just using SELECT and make it on VIEW...?
2. How can we set the next date_end null value like in idt=2 and another idt, with date_played that already set like in the question no.1, just using SELECT and make it on VIEW?

please help...Thanks

the sample for the result like the following table...if it's not possible...how to get it with update?

```
idt    date_played          date_end               duration
1      2013-03-13 22:33:48  2013-03-13 21:58:20    00:35:28
2      2013-03-13 21:58:20  2013-03-13 22:00:31    00:02:11
3      2013-03-13 22:00:31  2013-03-13 22:01:03    00:00:32
4      2013-03-13 22:01:03  2013-03-13 22:37:45    00:36:42
5      2013-03-13 22:37:45  2013-03-13 22:39:15    00:01:30
6      2013-03-13 22:39:15  2013-03-13 23:04:37    00:25:12
7      2013-03-13 23:04:37  2013-03-13 23:06:14    00:01:37
.
.
.
TILL THE END
```

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a solution like this, that makes use of MySql variables:

```
SELECT
  idt,
  date_played,
  date_end,
  duration
FROM (
  SELECT
    v_currentshow.idt,
    CASE WHEN date_played IS NULL THEN @start ELSE date_played END date_played,
    CASE WHEN date_end IS NULL THEN
           CASE WHEN date_played IS NULL THEN @start ELSE date_played END
           + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(duration) SECOND
         ELSE date_end
    END date_end,
    @start :=
      CASE WHEN date_end IS NULL THEN
             CASE WHEN date_played IS NULL THEN @start ELSE date_played END
             + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(duration) SECOND
           ELSE date_end
      END,
    duration
  FROM
   v_currentshow,
   (SELECT @start := null) r
) s
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71762/1). If you are sure that there are no gaps, and that every row exept the first one has null values, this query could be simplified a lot more.

Comment: thank you @fthiella, I saw fiddle...and it works...it works like a charm...:)

but when I tried on mysql in localhost...I found trouble...

Comment: i tried it..and it works like a charm...but when i tried it on localhost...the date_played field shows [BLOB - 19B]

here's the link to show the snapshot..

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?vf4f9re3mf3ct#

Answer (score 0):

You should do the processing in PHP, if the query sounds crazy you probably are better off post-processing with PHP.

My solution seems valid because you tagged your issue with `PHP`.

Admitting that your query returns an array, you could do that:

```
$results = array(); // the array of results returned by the query
$previousEndDate = null; // default it to null to avoid weird situations

foreach ($results as &$row) { // you can replace the pointer (&) with a new array that gets the proper values injected into it ~ but it's more readable because it highlights the most important lines

    if ($row['date_played'] === null && $previousEndDate !== null) {
        $row['date_played'] = $previousEndDate;
    }

    if ($row['date_end'] === null) {
        $dateInterval = new DateInterval('P0000-00-00T'. $row['duration']); // we create a valid PHP interval to add on top of the date_played
        $datePlayed = new DateTime($row['date_played']); // create a valid DateTime object off the SQL value
        $row['date_end'] = $datePlayed->add($dateInterval); // and we add the interval to the datePlayed
    }

    $previousEndDate = $row['date_end'];
}
```

More docs about [DateTime object](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval object](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).
As a bonus, the code above could support timezones.

You can then save these values back in the DB; I would not use a one-query-does-it solution because it might take more time and slow down your DB significantly.